# PDO PARAM_STR and length

Tags: php, pdo

I don't understand the length option in a `PDO PARAM_*` statement.

Does the length indicate an amount of required characters, or is it a max?

Example:

```
$sth->bindParam(2, $color, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
```

Does this require 12 characters, or is this limiting it to 12 characters? Or, am I completely misunderstanding what this is doing?

Comment: Which part of the description in the manual is hard for you to understand in specific? *"**length** - Length of the data type. To indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the length."* - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: @hakra - is it LIMITED to 12 characters, or does it REQUIRE 12 characters.

Comment: A follow-up on this Q -- is the length in _characters_, or in _bytes_?  I can't find anything that distinguishes the two.  Obviously it only matters if you're using multibyte characters, which is exactly why I need to know.  I'm leaning towards assuming bytes, since a too-large-based-on-bytes value seems safer than a too-short-based-on-characters value that might truncate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an indication of how how much data you wish to receive in the output parameter, the server will not send more than this.

So, to answer your question, it's a limitation rather than a requirement.