# When is the PDO Constants PDO::PARAM_STR used?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When is the PDO Constant `PDO::PARAM_STR` used? I know, when it's used in a `select`, it'll give you `x` number of characters. Is it also used in `Inserts`? Just how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you don't quite understand the meaning of this constant.

First, it's query independent.
Second, it is not for giving you "x characters" but to tell PDO how to treat a bound variable.

You can use this constant for almost every bound variable, or don't use it all:

```
$name = 'Joe';
$stm  = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name=?");
$stm->execute(array($name));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

this way `PDO::PARAM_STR` would be used silently.

Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: From the example on that page `$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);` Why is it used here and what will it do here?

Comment: it is used to tell the driver that $colour variable have to be formatted as string. STR means string.

Comment: I tried this: ``$sql = 'select names from names where names=:what';
$what = "james";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':what', $what, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
 
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{  
    echo $row['names'] . "<br>";  
}`` The output is James all the time.

Comment: And the number 12 has nothing to do with this constant and you can read it's meaning on the page I linked above.

Comment: I know this question is old, but If anyone still wondering what is the `12` for check here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/12241484/5413283